PWA mailto protocol_handlers works only first time in Chrome and Edge Browser
After installing Chrome/Edge app by clicking on Install App.
When I click any mailto: link anywhere on any different web page, windows open dialog box correctly asks for the Chrome first time. Windows opens the app and correctly redirects the app but only once.
I close the PWA App, and then I click on mailto:, it tries to open Windows's own Mail App.
I have created manifest.json for the website and it loads correctly. I have enabled protocol handlers as shown below.
    "protocol_handlers": [
      {
        "protocol": "mailto",
        "url": "/send-mail?url=%s"
      }
    ]

I am wondering if I am missing any step.
Is there any event handler I need to respond to?
